# Mask numpy array based on index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How do I mask an array based on the actual index values?

That is, if I have a 10 x 10 x 30 matrix and I want to mask the array when the first and second index equal each other.

For example, `[1, 1 , :]`  should be masked because 1 and 1 equal each other but `[1, 2, :]` should not because they do not.

I'm only asking this with the third dimension because it resembles my current problem and may complicate things. But my main question is, how to mask arrays based on the value of the indices?

Comment: Off topic, your avatar matches your question topic nicely :P

Comment: Yep, just trying to draw Z's all over my code. Thanks for helping me with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, to access the value of the indices, you can use `np.meshgrid`:

```py
i, j, k = np.meshgrid(*map(np.arange, m.shape), indexing='ij')
m.mask = (i == j)
```

The advantage of this method is that it works for arbitrary boolean functions on `i`, `j`, and `k`.  It is a bit slower than the use of the `identity` special case.

```py
In [56]: %%timeit
   ....: i, j, k = np.meshgrid(*map(np.arange, m.shape), indexing='ij')
   ....: i == j
10000 loops, best of 3: 96.8 µs per loop
```

---

As @Jaime points out, `meshgrid` supports a `sparse` option, which doesn't do so much duplication, but requires a bit more care in some cases because they don't broadcast.  It will save memory and speed things up a little.  For example,

```py
In [77]: x = np.arange(5)

In [78]: np.meshgrid(x, x)
Out[78]: 
[array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]),
 array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]])]

In [79]: np.meshgrid(x, x, sparse=True)
Out[79]: 
[array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]),
 array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])]
```

So, you can use the `sparse` version as he says, but you must force the broadcasting as such:

```py
i, j, k = np.meshgrid(*map(np.arange, m.shape), indexing='ij', sparse=True)
m.mask = np.repeat(i==j, k.size, axis=2)
```

And the speedup:

```py
In [84]: %%timeit
   ....: i, j, k = np.meshgrid(*map(np.arange, m.shape), indexing='ij', sparse=True)
   ....: np.repeat(i==j, k.size, axis=2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 73.9 µs per loop
```

Comment: Why not use `np.arange` instead of `range`, should save time.

Comment: Nice use of `map`... But you are creating 3 full masks of `(10, 10, 30)`... If you set `sparse=True` in the call to `np.meshgrid`, you reduce the memory footprint substantially, but you need to include all dimensions in the creation of the mask, e.g. `(i == j) & (k >= 0)` runs twice as fast as your solution.

Comment: Thanks @Jaime, I was trying to figure out how to do it with the sparser versions but couldn't!

Comment: It's a pity that boolean mask indexing does not support broadcasting. There may be some good reason for it, but it would make some operations ridiculously easy.

Comment: `sparse=True` seems like a lot of trouble for 8us, at least in this case :).

Comment: @BiRico Yep, just there for completeness.  Honestly, if time is an issue, the `np.identity` answer is best anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In your special case of wanting to mask the diagonals, you can use the `np.identity()` function which returns ones along the diagonal.  Since you have the third dimension, we have to add that third dimension to the the identity matrix:

```
m.mask = np.identity(10)[...,None]*np.ones((1,1,30))
```

There might be a better way of constructing that array, but it is basically stacking 30 of the `np.identity(10)` array.  For example, this is equivalent:

```
np.dstack((np.identity(10),)*30)
```

but slower:

```
In [30]: timeit np.identity(10)[...,None]*np.ones((1,1,30))
10000 loops, best of 3: 40.7 µs per loop

In [31]: timeit np.dstack((np.identity(10),)*30)
1000 loops, best of 3: 219 µs per loop
```

And @Ophion's suggestions

```
In [33]: timeit np.tile(np.identity(10)[...,None], 30)
10000 loops, best of 3: 63.2 µs per loop

In [71]: timeit np.repeat(np.identity(10)[...,None], 30)
10000 loops, best of 3: 45.3 µs per loop
```

Comment: `np.tile(np.identity(10)[...,None], 30)`

Comment: Well thats interesting. `tile` is basically a wrapper on `repeat`. So if you run `np.repeat(np.identity(10)[...,None], 30, axis=-1)` you skip some extra `if` statements, but `np.identity(10)[...,None]*np.ones((1,1,30))` is universally faster for any array size in 1 dimension. Good to know.

Comment: @Ophion Cool, I'd never considered that along dimensions of length 1, `tile` and `repeat` are equivalent.

Comment: You do have to specify an axis as `np.repeat` is odd, instead of the default `axis=-1` as with most function it is `axis=None`. If you do not explicitly pass the axis keyword you get a 1D array out and will have to reshape it manually.